# Application doesn't oriented

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

My application doesn't oriented even if I use

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
    return YES;
}
```

the only thing I do is to hide the lower tab bar using

```
SearchScreen.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES ;
```

Any idea how to fix that

Comment: Is it tab bar based application??

Comment: @ARC yes it's a tab based application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Are the "Supported Device Orientations" set properply?
- Maybe a parent ViewController is not allowing interface orientation?
- If testing on a device: Is it "orientation locked"?

**Setting 'Supported Device Orientations' inside Info.plist:**

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Supported Device Orientations not in xcode 3.2 , nd I am sure all the viewcontroller allowing interface orientation

Comment: @AMH Why are you using outdated software? You can set the supported device orientations inside Info.plist

Comment: can the device lock the orientation

Comment: the device orientation was locked, I don't know why thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Please write 
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
    return YES;
}

in all your tab bar's root view controller.

Can you tell me your which one is root view controller that tab view controller??